# Adding SlimScroll to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, slimscroll

I tried adding the SlimScroll to an iframe, but for some reason it isn't working.

```
<div id="-my-profile"><iframe id="scroll" height="525" width="912" src="/index/8"></iframe></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#scroll').slimScroll();
    });
</script>
```

I read the documentation about slimscroll and I found nothing about iframe.
What could be the problem? Is it working only with divs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. in "/index/8" page add:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
           $('body or .container or #content').slimScroll();
       });
   </script>
   ```
2. add scrolling="no" to iframe:

   ```
   <div id="-my-profile"><iframe scrolling="no" height="525" width="912" src="/index/8"></iframe></div>
   ```